# Read text from edit control in MFC and VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, mfc

I'm writing a simple MFC application with a Dialog window and some buttons.
I added also a edit control in order to let user insert a text string.

I'd like to read the value which is present in the edit control and to store it in a string but i do not know how to do this.

I have no compilation error, but I always read only a "." mark.

I added a variable name to the text edit control which is `filepath1` and this is the code:

```
    // CMFC_1Dlg dialog
    class CMFC_1Dlg : public CDialogEx
    {
    // Construction
    public:
        CMFC_1Dlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);    // standard constructor

    // Dialog Data
        enum { IDD = IDD_MFC_1_DIALOG };

        protected:
        virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support


    // Implementation
    protected:
        HICON m_hIcon;

        // Generated message map functions
        virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
        afx_msg void OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam);
        afx_msg void OnPaint();
        afx_msg HCURSOR OnQueryDragIcon();
        DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
    public:
        afx_msg void OnBnClickedButton1();
        afx_msg void OnBnClickedButton2();
        afx_msg void OnEnChangeEdit1();
        CString filePath1;
    }

    //...
void CMFC_1Dlg::OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ((nID & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX)
    {
        CAboutDlg dlgAbout;
        dlgAbout.DoModal();
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnSysCommand(nID, lParam);
    }
}

    CMFC_1Dlg::CMFC_1Dlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
        : CDialogEx(CMFC_1Dlg::IDD, pParent)
        ,filePath1(("..\\Experiments\\Dirs\\"))
    {
        m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
    }

    void CMFC_1Dlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
    {
        CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
        DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT1, filePath1);

    }

    // then i try to get the string value with
    CString txtname=filePath1;
    _cprintf("Value %s\n", txtname); // but i always read just a "."
```

Comment: First you need to add a control variable that controls the edit box. That way you can use the variable to read the text.

Comment: yes, i already added it as I specified in the topic.
The problem is that in this way i'm only able to read the first character and not the whole string.

For example, if i write "Hello" in the text box, txtname contains only "H"

Comment: I'm not seeing a `CEdit` variable.

Comment: To be honest, i didn't understand very well the CEdit variable. When i add a variable to a text control, VS add me the CEdit variable but it is not a String variable, so how i have to use it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
_cprintf("Value %S\n", txtname.GetString());
```

Note the capital 'S'

or you can cast:

```
_cprintf("Value %S\n", (LPCTSTR)txtname);
```

You would be better off using an edit control. To create a `CEdit` variable, right click on the edit box in VS and select "Add Member Variable", give the variable a name and click OK.

You can then retrieve the text in the edit box like this:

```
CEdit m_EditCtrl;
// ....
CString filePath1;
m_EditCtrl.GetWindowText(filePath1);
```

Comment: Yes, now it works.
However, i realized that it always print the initial value. If I manually change the text value in the edit control, it continues to display the old value.
With: filePath1(("..\\Experiments\\Dirs\\"))
If i delete it and i insert a new value, it always print the old one. Is there the possibility to refresh store the new value typed by the user?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is all the code, but I'm not seeing the `CEdit` variable. You can use the variable to get text in the edit box with `CEdit::GetWindowText()`. To create a `CEdit` variable, right click on the edit box in VS and select "Add Member Variable".

Comment: I have the CEdit filePath1 variable in CMFC_1Dlg : public CDialogEx but I do not know how to use it.
Don't I need a string value to store the text?

Comment: The code you provided shows that filePath1 is of type `CString`, not `CEdit`

Comment: Yes i did a mistake when I copied the code.
May be a solved with GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT1, Edit1); where IDC_EDIT1 is the text box.
CString txtname;
GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT1, txtname);
_cprintf("Value %S\n", txtname.GetString());
It seems to work now..

Answer (score 2):

I think your original code was OK for DDX use and `CString`. The advice to use a control variable and avoid the DDX/DDV functions is really one of preference and not the issue.

I suspect you are compiling with the UNICODE libraries but explicitly calling an ASCII function `_cprintf`. UNICODE is held as two bytes, for ASCII characters one of these will be 0. If you pass this to an ASCII string function it will stop after the first character.

If you are using UNICODE then call `_cwprintf` or use the `tchar.h` macro `_tcprintf` which will call the correct version for the compiler switch.

Tip: If you are targeting UNICODE only and will never require MBCS support then avoid using the `tchar.h` macros as they will obscure any issues with `char` and `TCHAR` data type mixing.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create a `CEdit` control variable using "Add Variable List".
Step 2: Use `GetDlgItemText()` to hold the text of that edit control.

Example: such as `CEdit` control list variable is `mc_strChatPane`, then `GetDlgItemText(mc_strChatPane, message)` where message is a user defined `CString` variable.