# How to convert CEdit type of data in to CString type data and how to display that in a messagebox?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, mfc

I would like to know how the data from CEdit(Entered by user) is displayed on Message box.

I would like to accept input from user and need to display it in a messagebox.Simple but i'm not able to convert CEdit type(input by user) to CString type(Which i have to display in Messagebox).

Here is my Code Snippet

```
In .h file
    CEdit* pEdit = new CEdit;
    CString text;

In .cpp file
    pEdit.Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | WS_BORDER,
                CRect(150, 10, 500, 50), this, 1);
    pEdit.GetWindowText(text);
```

Comment: Use `GetWindowText`, as already mentioned in this [duplicate post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11065919/1553090), and probably many others.

Comment: Please elaborate....

Comment: Your updated code snippit won't even compile... you need `pEdit->` instead of `.`, and if you already have `GetWindowText`, then what is the problem? (*don't* update the question with answers!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have created  Textbox programatically.

**EDIT:**
Declare `CEdit` in header file

```
CEdit* pEdit;
```

Write this code in `OnInitdialog()` function

```
pEdit = new CEdit; 
pEdit->Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | WS_BORDER,CRect(150, 10, 500, 50), this, 1);
```

Now on click of any button you can show messagebox. For example

```
OnButtonOk()
{
    CString strText;
    pEdit->GetWindowText(strText);
    AfxMessageBox(strText);
}
```

Comment: This is how i created Textbox programatically                                                           CEdit* pEdit = new CEdit;
pEdit.Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | WS_BORDER,CRect(150, 10, 500, 50), this, 1);

Comment: @YateeshKR, I have updated code. check Edit once.

Comment: @Yateesh Important that you notice @Himanshu has used `->` on the pointer which I don't think you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

There are two methodes do that.

You can bind your edit control to a `CString` variable. when you want get text data, call `UpdateData(TRUE)` and the CString variable stored the text stirng data.

Also it can work as below:

```
CString textStr;
CEdit* pEdit = new CEdit;
//call when you want get text
pEdit ->GetWindowText(textStr);
```

Comment: i have created a Textbox programatically so i'm not able to find CEDIT_CONTROL_ID

Comment: I changed my code, you need use `->` instead of `.`, then your code can worked, I tested it. Maybe your question is when call `GetWindowText` function? You can register a callback function for a button, the callback function call the `GetWindowText` function.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for CEdit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7yhsd2b.aspx) clearly states:

> To set and retrieve text from a CEdit object, use the CWnd member functions SetWindowText and GetWindowText, which set or get the entire contents of an edit control, even if it is a multiline control.

So given your creation of the `CEdit` object,

```
CString strOut;
pEdit->GetWindowText(strOut);
```

[CWnd::GetWindowText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db50wx7h.aspx)