# calling MFC edit control GetWindowText member can't compile

Tags: c++, mfc

My code:

```
//the auto generated stuff (by right-click on editbox add variable to control option)
CEdit edit_name;

void CSendMessageWithActualDataDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDIT_NAME, edit_name);
}
```

Looks OK so far, right?

```
void dofoo()
{
     //IDE shows error squiggle at dot "name.GetWi" with no pop-up 
     //details given except the object's blurb text
 
    CString foostring= edit_name.GetWindowTextW(); 
    //error C2661: 'CWnd::GetWindowTextW': no overloaded function takes 0 arguments


    // or instead with no parentheses added:

    // no IDE error indication
    CString foostring= edit_name.GetWindowTextW;
    //error C3867: 'CWnd::GetWindowTextW': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

}
```

According to:

[Read text from edit control in MFC and VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065919/read-text-from-edit-control-in-mfc-and-vs2010)

```
You can then retrieve the text in the edit box like this:
CEdit m_EditCtrl;
// ....
CString filePath1 = m_EditCtrl.GetWindowText()
.
.
.
// Yes, now it works...
```

I swear, this is like pulling teeth.

Comment: The edit control inherits [`GetWindowText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=msvc-170#getwindowtext) from `CWnd`. The modus operandi for invoking that member is to either pass a buffer+size, or pass a CString reference. If intellisense had any intelli-gence it would be telling you this when you typed in the member function name and hinted the opssible calling contexts to you. Your code should be `CString str; edit_name.GetWindowText(str);`

Comment: So how did it work for the fellow (without any extra steps) in the link I referred to?   I just assumed that by using the "add variable" to control option,  the IDE would wire up some stubby code to make it possible to just call a member function without having to mess with buffering.   Just  m_EditCtrl.GetWindowText() exactly as worked for that other guy, supposedly.

Comment: Key words: "supposedly" indeed. No clue. You could just use a [DDX_Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/standard-dialog-data-exchange-routines?view=msvc-170#ddx_text) against a `CString` member, btw, and just cut out the middle man (the control object) if all you're interested in is exchanging data in/out and have no other plans for the control (like disablement, etc.). Just another option.

Comment: I'll look into the DDX, quite a newbie on that, but I would have assumed any kind of stubby thing I was thinking would be overriding GetWindowText  (don't know if that's possible),  but I suppose one long term route would be just make a wrapper that takes a reference to the control, does the call, buffering yada yada, gives me a string pointer.

Comment: You *could* derive a class from a `CEdit`, implement a `GetWindowText` overload that takes zero arguments and returns a `CString` object, and hook it up using `DDX_Control`. Wouldn't be worth it, if all you need is just standard behavior a `CEdit` (or `DDX_Text` even) provides.

Comment: Probably easier just to write a templated wrapper class or function that takes a window-derived object and returns a text pointer.   In any case I hate screwing with buffers when computers can be told how to do it with a line of code.

Comment: *You* don't have to *"screw with buffers"*, `CString` does that for you already. Just pass a reference and everything is fine. If MFC were implemented today, `GetWindowText` would probably just return a `CString` object directly.

Comment: Right, kind of like good ol crappy VB did twenty five years ago.  =control.text, =control.caption etc That's where I'm coming from, in case anyone hadn't guessed.   Reinventing the wheel is a such a waste of time when max clock-tick performance is the furthest thing from mind.

Comment: so when I do something like
CString s;
edit_name.GetWindowText(s);

...intellisense doesn't show any sensible info about what GetWindowText is expecting as arguments,  but sure, it turns out to work, but I wouldn't have guessed this far

Comment: So I can move on, but what was that guy talking about?   GetWindowText().

Thanks yuall for the input.

Comment: @PhilG which guy was talking about `GetWindowText()` and where? There is no `GetWindowText()` without arguments. Read the relevant section [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=msvc-170#getwindowtext)

Comment: re Jabberwocky

It was from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065919/read-text-from-edit-control-in-mfc-and-vs2010


the original accepted answer read as follows

```
You can then retrieve the text in the edit box like this:
CEdit m_EditCtrl;
// ....
CString filePath1 = m_EditCtrl.GetWindowText()
.
.
.
// Yes, now it works...
```

but has been corrected by Andrew Truckle

Comment: No, it has been corrected by me, because the code was wrong.

Comment: The post on a ten year old question (that got me off on the wrong foot)
"Read text from edit control in MFC and VS2010"
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065919/read-text-from-edit-control-in-mfc-and-vs2010
is marked as "edited by Andrew Truckle"

Comment: Like anything else on Stack Overflow, it also has a [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11066024/revisions). Why would I attempt to misrepresent events?

Comment: I had never clicked the (any) edit link till now, and do see your GetWindowText edit.  No doubt listing only the most recent reviser on the main page keeps from cluttering things up,  but maybe a dropdown list showing all contributors could be a worthwhile feature.

Answer (score 1):

When you add a EDIT control to a dialog, and you go to map it to a variable, you have two choices:

1. Control
2. Value

[image]

If you select **Value**, then you can map it to a `CString`:

[image]

This creates the [`DDX_Text`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/standard-dialog-data-exchange-routines?view=msvc-170#ddx_text) entry that was referred to in the comments:

```
void CTestDialogDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT1, m_strText);
}
```

Or, you can use [`GetDlgItemText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=msvc-170#getdlgitemtext) if you want to just get the value directly from the control, and avoid creating a variable. This shows both:

```
void CTestDialogDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    // This way you get the current text value from the edit control, without even creating a CEdit control member variable
    CString strText;

    GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT1, strText);

    AfxMessageBox(strText);

    // This way we use our mapped CString to the EDIT control
    UpdateData(TRUE);
    AfxMessageBox(m_strText);
}
```

If you do decide to map to a `CEdit` (a **Control** instead of a **Value**) then as you found out:

```
// Get the value from the control
m_editText.GetWindowText(strText);
AfxMessageBox(strText);
```

I assume your linked article is incorrect as `GetWindowText` does not return a `CString`.

---

By the way, with Visual Assist (a third-party extension) it shows the options correctly for Intellisense:

[image]

---

By the way, you may find this article useful ([Dialog box controls and variable types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/adding-a-member-variable-visual-cpp?view=msvc-170#dialog-box-controls-and-variable-types)). If you look at the table and find **EDIT**:

[image]

The above is with the previous rows on the table stripped out. As you can see, you can map the EDIT to more types of variables than just a `CString`.

Comment: Thank you for the detail and links.  I confess if I had bothered to read an intro to MFC,  oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this is all about convenience. Since you already know how to call [`CWnd::GetWindowText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#getwindowtext), but find it too cumbersome to use, just wrap everything up in a free function:

```cpp
CString GetWindowText(CWnd const& wnd) {
    CString s;
    wnd.GetWindowText(s);
    return s;
}
```

You can call that, passing in any object that (publicly) derives from `CWnd` (such as the `CEdit edit_name`) and get a `CString` object you can use any which way. (C++17 introduced guaranteed copy elision, meaning that `s` will never need to get copied.)

If you need to pass it into other Windows API functions that expect an `LPCTSTR`, `CString` implements [`operator PCXSTR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class#operator_pcxstr) that implicitly converts things as needed, e.g.

```cpp
AfxMessageBox(GetWindowText(edit_name));
```

Answer (score 0):

this suffices:

```
class GetWindowText
        {
            CString s;
            public:
                GetWindowText(CWnd &w){w.GetWindowText(s);}
                ~GetWindowText() {}
                CString operator()() {return s;}
        };


just call like this:

MessageBoxW(GetWindowText(edit_name)());
```

Comment: Why on earth are you doing all that? Find a good tutorial on MFC and learn how to use CEdit properly.

Comment: Also, if all you want is a string, then why not map the control to a CString directly in the Resource Editor?

Comment: All that?  I used the IDE, as I said, right-click-assign a variable to the control, as is the given option, and tried to use it in a most intuitive way,.  What other steps do I have to take?  Thanks for being dismissively uninformative.

Comment: And you miss the extremely obvious.  An edit control is ALL ABOUT STRINGS.   Why should I have to manually go in and map anything when that should be the default implemented by the great wisdom of the IDE?

Comment: And what's hilarious here, using that little class I mentioned added via an include would add up to much less editing time than anything you're suggesting.  Not only that, you thoroughly ignored the original question about using control.GetWindowText() (control added as a variable using the IDE) working with no args as APPARENTLY works for some, unless they were being carelessly inspecific in their description, or they were lying.

Comment: When you map a control you can map it to a control or a value. If you set it to map to a value then you can tell it to map to a CString. Then when you use UpdateData the mapped variable will have the right text value.

Comment: Ok, some keywords to work with (UpdateData)  leading to relevant documentation.  That's better than I just don't know what I'm doing and should read more.

Comment: I just added an answer with some thoughts about this. Keep with it my friend - once you get it you'll be OK.

Comment: Please see the documentation for [`GetBuffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class#getbuffer). All you have done is, in an attempt to not fiddle with buffers, you opened it up to clients trashing them. This is hideously dangerous code. And given that `CString` already implements `operator LPCTSTR` it's a mystery why. `CString MyGetWindowText(CWnd const &w) { CString s; w.GetWindowText(s); return s: }`. There, a clean, simple, free function (that's both more versatile and far safer).

Comment: Usage example: `MessageBoxW(MyGetWindowText(edit_name));` (not only safer, but also shorter, and more obvious).

Comment: Yes, I see, GetBuffer, big mistake.  Don't know how I missed  GetString.

Comment: That's still a convoluted mess of what should be a function. There's a destructor, that does nothing. And while it's non-`virtual` the class is missing the `final` specifier. The real killer, though: Its constructor stores the currently held value, and by the time `operator()` is run, that value could have changed. Plus, `operator()` suggests a function call, making absolutely sure that readers of the code will instinctively misinterpret it. Yes, a mess indeed.